# What to position a div relative to a div relative to a div

Tags: html, css, position

I would like to produce the following template with **div** elements

The idea is that I would like a **div** element to have a specific position relative to another **div** element containing it that would be itself positioned relatively to another **div** element containing it.

I get the relation between two **div** elements by making one have a **position:absolute** and the *container* having a **position:relative**

But how to I make it all relative to the *big* container.

Here is an image explaining what i'm describing on top and what i'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: As long as your div's container is positioned, that means you can position your div relatively to it. So it doesn't matter if the container is positioned `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`. In other words, you can have a `relative` div, an `absolute` div inside it and another `absolute` div inside of that, ad infinitum. Does that answer your question?

Comment: That said, your picture looks more like a good old table than a bunch of nested positioned divs.

Comment: Here is what i am trying to achieve as en example : http://jsfiddle.net/MB4Fd/910/   Now consider all inside div to fit inside the *parent* div. Also to make it possible to have several div on the same *line* but i think i can achieve this with a *float* property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do some code for you on JSFiddle. Here you go:

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8gjofg01/)

You can enlarge the output window's width and then set width etc according to your project.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.outer_div {
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner_div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner_div .box:nth-child(3n) {
  margin: 0;
}

.inner_div .box {
  border: 3px solid #03A9F4;
  width: 172px;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.inner_div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: block;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner_div:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="outer_div">
    <div class="inner_div">
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>

      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="inner_div">
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what i am trying to achieve. Thank you all for the help. I will try to understand how you achieved this.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you may need more help. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.div1 {
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
}
.div2 {
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}
.div3 {
    width:33.3%;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Or you can simply use HTML Tables.

Answer (score 0):

To explore another possibility, here is a flexbox example:
http://codepen.io/JKudla/pen/evPJPW

CSS:

```
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article {
  width: 33.3333%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<main>
  <section>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
  </section>
</main>
```